# Custom ticks are behaving odd in pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

I have the dataframe below and I want to have custom ticks on x-axis like [0 1 ... 23]. But when I do plt.customticks all the ticks are just squeezed to left side. How to place them equally?

```
    timestamp               capacity available
0   03/05/2023 00:55:16 19  15
1   03/05/2023 00:56:16 19  15
2   03/05/2023 00:57:16 19  15
3   03/05/2023 00:58:17 19  15
4   03/05/2023 00:59:17 19  15
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df["available"])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('# of available items')
times=list(range(24))
#timestrings = [str(num) for num in times]
plt.xticks(times)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add some minimal reproducible code to show how you created the plot.  What kind of plot? Plotted via pandas or directly via matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code, the ticks are getting set from 0-23, but matplotlib automatically checks the values (0-4) and assigns the line for just 0 thru 4. So, you need to change the `plt.xticks()` line to below...

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0], plt.gca().get_xlim()[1], (plt.gca().get_xlim()[1] - plt.gca().get_xlim()[0])/24), times)
```

Basically, `xticks` are now forced to have ticks at locations `plt.gca().get_xlim()[0]` - which is the minimum/smallest tick to `plt.gca().get_xlim()[1]` - which the maximum/largest tick and the ticklabels are set to `times` which is an array of 0 thru 23. This way, the tick values will be from 0-4, while the ticklabels will be from 0-23. This will give you the plot below...

[image]